# Data not being stored in variable

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to add data to an empty var, but data is not getting stored.
When calling `hotel_list`, it shows empty. What am I missing? Thanks!

```
var hotelData = JSON.parse(data);

function hotelList(){
    var hotel_list = '';
    for (i = 0; i < hotelData.length; i++) {
        function list(index, hotel) {
            hotel_list += '<li class="hotel" data-index="'+ index +'">'+ hotel.name +'</li>';
            document.getElementById("hotel-listing").innerHTML = hotel_list;
        };
    };
};

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    hotelList();
});
```

Comment: You're defining a function inside the loop, but never calling it.

Comment: For loops don't use callbacks. Are you confusing `for` with `each` or `forEach`?

Comment: Probably, I want to iterate hotelData, but I don't know how to pass (index,hotel) into the forEach loop

Comment: You don't have a forEach loop, you have a for loop. Remove the function and replace `index` with `i` and `hotel` with `hotelData[i]`.

Comment: I basically want to make this look as pure JS:

    $.each(data, function(index, hotel) {
        hotel_list += '<li class="hotel" data-index="'+ index +'">'+ hotel.name +'</li>';
    });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var data = '[{"name": "h1"}, {"name": "h2"}]';
var hotelData = JSON.parse(data);

function hotelList(){
    var hotel_list = '';
    (hotelData || []).forEach(function (hotel, index) {
            hotel_list += '<li class="hotel" data-index="'+ index +'">'+ hotel.name +'</li>';
        });
     document.getElementById("hotel-listing").innerHTML = hotel_list;
};

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    hotelList();
});
```

```html
<div id="hotel-listing"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, works like a charm. What does (hotelData || []) mean?

Comment: If "hotelData" is undefined, the function does not throws an error. If you are sure about it's value, you can omit this and use simply "hotelData.forEach(...".